# Ordering span elements independent of text directionality

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

Say we have a number of span text elements (2 or more) with 'dir' specified as RTL:

```
<div dir="rtl">
<span>First-Element</span>
<span>Second-Element</span>
<span>Third-Element</span>
</div>
```

and we would like them to appear in order from right to left:

```
Third-Element Second-Element First-Element
```

This works fine if the text elements have RTL directionality (text from Arabic, Farsi, Hebrew etc.), or if they are interleaved with RTL elements:

```
<div dir="rtl">
<span>First-Element-RTL</span>
<span>Second-Element-RTL</span>
<span>Third Element-RTL</span>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div dir="rtl">
<span>First-Element-LTR</span>
<span>Second-Element-RTL</span>
<span>Third Element-LTR</span>
</div>
```

But if all the elements are of LTR directionality, then the order of the language is used, and we get the **undesired ordering**:

```
First-Element Second-Element Third-Element
```

How can we achieve a fixed order of the elements independent of the directionality of the text in the elements - that is, the technique (whether html or css) should be indifferent to the language of individual text elements.

This issue arises when the content of span elements is variable and provided by the user, for example user names that can be in an RTL language or English.

**Edit**

I have to emphasize that we are talking about ordering the text spans relative to each other, not changing the flow of the text itself, so 'English Text' should appear as is, not as 'txeT hsilgnE'.

**Edit**

This is a simple HTML segment to test the answer provided by Jukka. This presents as 'bar foo' aligned to the right. It shows (at least on my browser) that there is no need for `{ unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }` at the container level to get the desired result.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        span { unicode-bidi: embed; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div dir="rtl">
<span>foo</span>
<span>bar</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
div { unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }
span { unicode-bidi: embed; }
```

The first rule forces a specific direction, in this case RTL as set in HTML, overriding the inherent directionality of text (which depends on the directionality properties of characters).

The second rule makes each `span` element an “autonomous island” in directionality, i.e. text direction inside it is not affected by enclosing elements but only on properties set on the element itself and on the directionality properties of characters. So e.g. Latin letters run left to right, Hebrew and Arabic letters right to left.

There’s a problem, though. If a `span` contains, say, “foo (2)”, it will be rendered as “(foo (2”. The reason is that the element has RTL direction, as inherited from the parent. Although the `dir` attribute, as well as the `direction` property, sets weak directionality only (which does not affect e.g. a sequence of Latin letters, which have strong LTR directionality), it affects e.g. situations where parentheses are involved. Parentheses have ambiguous directionality, so they are treated according to the weak directionality settings.

I’m afraid there’s no simple way around this part of the use. You can of course set the directionality of `span` elements according to the what you expect to be the most common situation, like `span { direction: ltr; }` if you expect texts to be in English mostly. But for a real solution, you would need to control the weak directionality settings according to the language of the content.

Comment: I don't see the bidi-override is necessary, the desired effect is achieved without it. Also: it overrides the bidi algorithm at the text level for inline elements. Say we have 'English text' at the div level outside spans, and RTL direction at the container level, then we would get 'txet hsilgnE', which is not what's desired.

Comment: Without bidi-override, the order of the spans follows the directionality of characters. So `<div dir=rtl><span>foo</span> <span>bar</span></div>` gets displayed as “foo bar”, just as it does without the `span` tags.

Comment: Are you sure?! I'm testing without bidi-override and getting "bar foo". Could it be a browser dependent thing ? I tested on FF and Chrome.

Comment: Yes, see http://jsfiddle.net/PCrAR/ (you might have something else on the page that affects the order).

Comment: I provided a simple test case if you like to check it on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just `<span>` elements that you need to have in LTR order, I would simply remove the `dir="rtl"` declaration from the parent `<div>`, or if it's set at a higher parent level, override it using that `<div>` by including `dir="ltr"`.

You can also force it on the children via CSS:

```
div {direction: ltr;}
div span {direction: ltr;}
```

Comment: Thx. The desired order of the elements is right to left, but with the extra condition that it should be independent of element text directionality - this independence of element text directionality is the issue of the question.

Comment: @Basel: In this case you should be able to achieve the effect you're after by using floats. Float the elements inside the parent container to left or right, according to your needs. This is independent of directionality.

Comment: Floating is a different concept from alignment, it might work in some cases but could cause undesired effects in others. Generally we would like to apply directional attributes/styles correctly. Say for example you have inline text at the div level in the above examples, then floating the spans right would cause the div level text to float left, when the desired effect is to have a general right to left flow.

Comment: For a discussion of the issues related to the question, please check: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#direction, http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2, http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup

Comment: @Basel ... I work extensively with RTL Arabic and seems to work fine in every case I've needed it. Ultimately, it's about shipping product.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the following achieve what you're looking for?
Pardon if I misunderstood your question, hence the question mark.

```
[dir="rtl"] > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/gR9gR/)

Answer (score -1):

If you still want to use LTR on each string, replace your `span` elements with a `table` and `td` elements.  Yes, you should usually avoid using tables for a single row like this (people tell you to use `div` or `span` instead) but nothing else seems to render consistently between browsers, and if a `table` is in HTML with `dir` set to `RTL`, the `td` elements in a `tr` will be rendered with the first on the right, the second to the left of that, and so on, even if consecutive `td` elements have their `dir` set to `LTR`.  Consecutive `span` elements set to LTR, on the other hand, seem to be clumped together as a single element when rendering in non-IE browsers if there happens to be a bit of left-to-right text outside of them.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="rtl"> <!--Direction marker in the HTML tag.-->
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.ltrCells {
            border-collapse: collapse; /* Removes extra borders */
            display: inline-table; /* Keeps the table from appearing on its own line. */
            vertical-align: bottom; /* Lines up the table text with previous and next text. */
        }
            table.ltrCells tbody tr td {
                padding-bottom: 0px; /* If not 0, text before and after the table gets pushed down. */
            }
    </style>
    <title>Tester</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span dir="rtl">Here's some stuff before</span>
    <table class="ltrCells">
        <tr>
            <td dir="ltr">first</td>
            <td dir="ltr">(Two) Second.</td>
            <td dir="ltr">שלישי) שלוש)</td>
            <td dir="ltr">ארבעה</td>
            <td dir="ltr">5</td>
            <td dir="ltr">(שישית Six)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <span dir="rtl">and some stuff after.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here's how it renders in IE9, Firefox 27, and Chrome 33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPIE7.png).  I'd put the image directly in here, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

For some reason the `span` elements before and after the `table` MUST have `dir="rtl"`, or they will render on the wrong sides of the table.

Comment: Someone's just going to vote it down without leaving any feedback for why?  That hardly tells me how to improve my answers in the future.

Comment: new design does not use TABLEs for positioning elements. The preferred way is using DIVs.